# How is a match word omitted in Scala?

Tags: scala

In Scala, you can do

```
list.filter { item =>
    item match {
      case Some(foo) => foo.bar > 0
    }
}
```

But you can also do the quicker way by omitting `match`:

```
list.filter {
  case Some(foo) => foo.bar > 0
}
```

How is this supported in Scala? Is this new in 2.9? I have been looking for it, and I can figure out what makes this possible. Is it just part of the Scala compiler?

Comment: In fact, your first variant is invalid. item is not defined (and should it be, it would not mean an element of the list). filter expect a function, you must write list.filter{item => item match... It is not just match that disappear.

Comment: @didierd, I edited the question to address your valid point, because I think there's still an interesting question here.

Comment: I didn't see anyone answering this point, but this has existed since I learned Scala, at the very least -- back on 2.7.x.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) addresses that in section 8.5. The relevant portions:

> An anonymous function can be deﬁned by a sequence of cases

```
{ case p1 => b1 ... case pn => bn }
```

> If the expected type is `scala.Functionk[S1, ..., Sk, R]` , the expression is taken to
>   be equivalent to the anonymous function:

```
(x1 : S1, ..., xk : Sk) => (x1, ..., xk) match {
  case p1 => b1 ... case pn => bn
}
```

> If the expected type is `scala.PartialFunction[S, R]`, the expression is taken to
>   be equivalent to the following instance creation expression:

```
new scala.PartialFunction[S, T ] {
  def apply(x: S): T = x match {
    case p1 => b1 ... case pn => bn
  }
  def isDefinedAt(x: S): Boolean = {
    case p1 => true ... case pn => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

So typing the expression as `PartialFunction` or a `Function` influences how the expression is compiled.

Also `trait PartialFunction [-A, +B] extends (A) ⇒ B` so a partial function `PartialFunction[A,B]` is also a `Function[A,B]`.

Comment: Yes, I think this answers the original question nicely. More info: when the expected type is a Function, as in the case of `Seq.filter`, this explains how `{ case ... }` gets used. For other methods, such as `Seq.collect`, the expected type is a PartialFunction, and then an expression `{ case ... }` *should* be required, rather than `x => x match { case ... }`; Jean-Philippe's answer handles that case, but note the strange compiler behavior described in my answer.

Comment: Going to go with this answer as the accepted answer because it covers what the compiler is doing pretty well. Thanks everybody for your answers.

Answer (score 18):

**Edit**: parts of this answer are wrong; please refer to [huynhjl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7170025/390581).

---

If you omit the `match`, you signal the compiler that you are defining a **partial function**. A partial function is a function that is not defined for every input value. For instance, your filter function is only defined for values of type `Some[A]` (for your custom type `A`).

`PartialFunction`s throw a `MatchError` when you try to apply them where they are not defined. Therefore, you should make sure, when you pass a `PartialFunction` where a regular `Function` is defined, that your partial function will never be called with an unhanded argument. Such a mechanism is very useful e.g. for unpacking tuples in a collection:

```
val tupleSeq: Seq[(Int, Int)] = // ...
val sums = tupleSeq.map { case (i1, i2) => i1 + i2 }
```

APIs which ask for a partial function, like the `collect` filter-like operation on collections, usually call `isDefinedAt` before applying the partial function. There, it is safe (and often wanted) to have a partial function that is not defined for every input value.

So you see that although the syntax is close to that of a `match`, it is actually quite a different thing we're dealing with.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but according to tests that I posted in my answer, the two expressions seem to behave exactly the same. Could it be a bug?

Comment: @Kipton, it turns out `{ case ... }` can be syntactic sugar for a `x match { case ...}` anonymous function - see my answer.

Comment: @huynhjl, I understand that, as spec'ed, the compiler converts `{ case ... }` to a Function of the form `x => x match { case ... }`. The bizarre thing is that the compiler also does the converse: converts `x => x match { case ...}` to a PartialFunction. I'm pretty sure this is not in the spec, and a compiler bug. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @Kipton, yes I see what you mean now.

Comment: @Kipton Indeed, thanks for your comments and complementary information!

Comment: `{ case ... }` can be both a partial function and a function -- it depends on the expected type.

Answer (score 6):

-- *Revised post* --

Hmm, I'm not sure I see a difference, Scala 2.9.1.RC3,

```
val f: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = { case 2 => 3 }
f.isDefinedAt(1) // evaluates to false
f.isDefinedAt(2) // evaluates to true
f(1) // match error

val g: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = x => x match { case 2 => 3 }
g.isDefinedAt(1) // evaluates to false
g.isDefinedAt(2) // evaluates to true
g(1) // match error
```

It seems `f` and `g` behave exactly the same as `PartialFunctions`.

Here's another example demonstrating the equivalence:

```
Seq(1, "a").collect(x => x match { case s: String => s }) // evaluates to Seq(a)
```

Even more interesting:

```
// this compiles
val g: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = (x: Int) => {x match { case 2 => 3 }}

// this fails; found Function[Int, Int], required PartialFunction[Int, Int]
val g: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = (x: Int) => {(); x match { case 2 => 3 }}
```

So there's some special casing at the compiler level to convert between `x => x match {...}`  and just `{...}`.

*Update*. After reading the language spec, this seems like a bug to me. I filed [SI-4940](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4940) in the bug tracker.

Comment: Did you mean g.isDefinedAt and not f? Also is g still a PartialFunction?

Comment: `g` and `f` both have type `PartialFunction`, yes.

Comment: Yea then I am just confused how scala knows the difference. It must be at compiler level. :/