# Scala: Try and casing on Success and Failure

Tags: scala

I've implemented the following code to handle the completion of my future, and it compiles fine

```
resultFuture.onComplete({
      case Success => // success logic
      case Failure => // failure logic
    })
```

I'm a little confused as to how it works, I'm presuming it does as I copied it from a similar example from the Scala documentation

I understand that onComplete requires a function that takes a Try as input, and that Success and Failure are case classes that extend from Try

What I don't understand is how you can case on these without first performing a match of some type.

How is this possible here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is a match word omitted in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168026/how-is-a-match-word-omitted-in-scala)

Comment: Before voting to close, please consider whether the OP would be at all likely to find the other post considered a duplicate.  Two questions with the same answer are not necessarily the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument being passed to `onComplete` is a [partial function](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction). Here is how you can define a partial function in the REPL:

```
val f: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 3 => "three"
  case 4 => "four"
}
```

Notice that the `match` keyword doesn't appear here.

`PartialFunction[Int, String]` is a subclass of `(Int => String)`, if you try to call it on a value that it's not defined on, a `MatchError` exception would be raised.

Whenever the compiler expects a parameter of type `Int=>String` a `PartialFunction[Int, String]` can be passed (since it's a subclass). Here is a somewhat contrived example:

```
def twice(func: Int => String) = func(3) + func(3)

twice({
  case 3 => "three"
  case 4 => "four"
})

res4: java.lang.String = threethree

twice({ case 2 => "two" })

scala.MatchError: 3 (of class java.lang.Integer)
```